# How do you manage the underlying codebase for a versioned API?

Tags: rest, versioning, api-versioning

I've been reading up on versioning strategies for ReST APIs, and something none of them appear to address is how you manage the underlying codebase.

Let's say we're making a bunch of breaking changes to an API - for example, changing our Customer resource so that it returns separate `forename` and `surname` fields instead of a single `name` field. (For this example, I'll use the URL versioning solution since it's easy to understand the concepts involved, but the question is equally applicable to content negotiation or custom HTTP headers)

We now have an endpoint at `http://api.mycompany.com/v1/customers/{id}`, and another incompatible endpoint at `http://api.mycompany.com/v2/customers/{id}`. We are still releasing bugfixes and security updates to the v1 API, but new feature development is now all focusing on v2. How do we write, test and deploy changes to our API server? I can see at least two solutions:

- Use a source control branch/tag for the v1 codebase. v1 and v2 are developed, and deployed independently, with revision control merges used as necessary to apply the same bugfix to both versions - similar to how you'd manage codebases for native apps when developing a major new version whilst still supporting the previous version.
- Make the codebase itself aware of the API versions, so you end up with a single codebase that includes both the v1 customer representation and the v2 customer representation. Treat versioning as part of your solution architecture instead of a deployment issue - probably using some combination of namespaces and routing to make sure requests are handled by the correct version.

The obvious advantage of the branch model is that it's trivial to delete old API versions - just stop deploying the appropriate branch/tag - but if you're running several versions, you could end up with a really convoluted branch structure and deployment pipeline. The "unified codebase" model avoids this problem, but (I think?) would make it much harder to remove deprecated resources and endpoints from the codebase when they're no longer required. I know this is probably subjective since there's unlikely to be a simple correct answer, but I'm curious to understand how organisations who maintain complex APIs across multiple versions are solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! I CANNOT believe more people are not answering this question!! I am sick and tired of everyone having an opinion regarding how versions enter a system, but no one seems to tackle the real hard problem of dispatching versions to their appropriate code. By now there should be atleast an array of accepted "patterns" or "solutions" to this seemingly common problem. Theres an insane number of questions on SO regarding "API versioning". Deciding how to accept versions is FRIKKIN SIMPLE (relatively)! Handling it in the codebase once it gets in, is HARD!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I've used both of the strategies you mention. Of those two, I favor the second approach, being simpler, in use cases that support it. That is, if the versioning needs are simple, then go with a simpler software design:

- A low number of changes, low complexity changes, or low frequency change schedule
- Changes that are largely orthogonal to the rest of the codebase: the public API can exist peacefully with the rest of the stack without requiring "excessive" (for whatever definition of of that term you choose to adopt) branching in code

I did not find it overly difficult to remove deprecated versions using this model:

- Good test coverage meant that ripping out a retired API and the associated backing code ensured no (well, minimal) regressions
- Good naming strategy (API-versioned package names, or somewhat uglier, API versions in method names) made it easy to locate the relevant code
- Cross-cutting concerns are harder; modifications to core backend systems to support multiple APIs have to be very carefully weighed. At some point, the cost of versioning backend  (See comment on "excessive" above) outweighs the benefit of a single codebase.

The first approach is certainly simpler from the standpoint of reducing conflict between co-existing versions, but the overhead of maintaining separate systems tended to outweigh the benefit of reducing version conflict. That said, it was dead simple to stand up a new public API stack and start iterating on a separate API branch. Of course, generational loss set in almost immediately, and the branches turned into a mess of merges, merge conflict resolutions, and other such fun.

A third approach is at the architectural layer: adopt a variant of the Facade pattern, and abstract your APIs into public facing, versioned layers that talks to the appropriate Facade instance, which in turn talks to the backend via its own set of APIs. Your Facade (I used an Adapter in my previous project) becomes its own package, self-contained and testable, and allows you to migrate frontend APIs independently of the backend, and of each other.

This will work if your API versions tend to expose the same kinds of resources, but with different structural representations, as in your fullname/forename/surname example. It gets slightly harder if they start relying on different backend computations, as in, "My backend service has returned incorrectly calculated compound interest that has been exposed in public API v1. Our customers have already patched this incorrect behavior. Therefore, I cannot update that computation in the backend and have it apply until v2. Therefore we now need to fork our interest calculation code." Luckily, those tend to be infrequent: practically speaking, consumers of RESTful APIs favor accurate resource representations over bug-for-bug backwards compatibility, even amongst non-breaking changes on a theoretically idempotent `GET`ted resource.

I'll be interested to hear your eventual decision.

Comment: Just curious, in the source code, do you duplicate models between v0 and v1 that didn't change? Or do you have v1 use some v0 models? To me, I'd be confused if I saw v1 using v0 models for some fields. But on the other hand, it would reduce code bloat. For handling multiple versions do we just have to accept and live with duplicative code for models that never changed?

Comment: My recollection is that our source code versioned models independently of the API itself, so for instance API v1 might use Model V1, and API v2 might also use Model V1. Basically, the internal dependency graph for the public API included both exposed API code, as well as backend "fulfillment" code such as server and model code. For multiple versions, the only strategy I've ever used is duplication of the whole stack--a hybrid approach (module A is duplicated, module B is versioned...) seems very confusing. YMMV of course. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what's suggested for the third approach. Are there any public examples of code that's structured like it?

Answer (score 17):

For me the second approach is better. I have use it for the SOAP web services and plan to use it for REST also.

As you write, the codebase should be version aware, but a compatibility layer can be used as separate layer. In your example, the codebase can produce resource representation (JSON or XML) with first and last name, but the compatibility layer will change it to have only name instead.

The codebase should implement only the latest version, lets say v3. The compatibility layer should convert the requests and response between the newest version v3 and the supported versions e.g v1 and v2.
The compatibility layer can have a separate adapters for each supported version which can be connected as chain.

For example:

Client v1 request:   v1 adapt to v2 ---> v2 adapt to v3 ----> codebase

Client v2 request:   v1 adapt to v2 (skip) ---> v2 adapt to v3 ----> codebase

For the response the adapters function simply in the opposite direction. If you are using Java EE, you can you the servlet filter chain as adapter chain for example.

Removing one version is easy, delete the corresponding adapter and the test code.

Comment: It is difficult to guarantee compatibility if the entire underlying code base has changed. Much safer to retain the old codebase for bug-fix releases.

Answer (score 6):

Branching seems much better for me, and i used this approach in my case.

Yes as you already mentioned - backporting bug fixes will require some effort, but at the same time supporting multiple versions under one source base (with routing and all other stuff) will require you if not less, but at least same effort, making system more complicated and monstrous with different branches of logic inside (at some point of versioning you definetely will come to huge `case()` pointing to version modules having code duplicated, or having even worse `if(version == 2) then...`) . 
Also dont forget that for regression purposes you still have to keep tests branched.

Regarding versioning policy: i would keep as max -2 versions from current, deprecating support for old ones - that would give some motivation for users to move.

Comment: I'm thinking about  testing in a single codebase at the moment. You mentioned that tests would always need to be branched but I'm thinking that all the tests for v1, v2, v3 etc could live in the same solution too and all be run at the same time.

I'm thinking of decorating the tests with attributes which specify what versions they support: e.g

`[Version(From="v1", To="v2")]`, 
`[Version(From="v2", To="v3")]`,
`[Version(From="v1")] // All versions`

Just exploring it now, ever heard anyone do it?

Comment: Well, after 3 years I've learned that there is no precise answer to original question :D. It is very project-dependent. If you can afford freezing the API and only maintain it (e.g. bugfixes) then I would still branch/detach the related code(API-related business logic + tests + rest endpoint) and have all shared stuff in separate library (with its own tests). If V1 is going to coexist with V2 for quite some time and feature work is still ongoing then I would keep them together and tests as well (covering V1, V2 etc. and named accordingly).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it seems to be quite an opinionated space. I'm going to try the one solution approach first and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, introduction of a major version of API leading you in a situation of having to maintain multiple versions is an event which does not (or should not) occur very frequently. However, it cannot be avoided completely. I think it is overall a safe assumption that a major version, once introduced, would stay latest version for relatively long period of time. Based on this,  I would prefer to achieve simplicity in the code at the expense of duplication as it gives me better confidence of not breaking previous version when I introduce changes in latest one.